# Unable to unblock Ideapad z570 broadcom wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, lenovo

I have a lenovo ideapad z570 laptop with BCM4313 adapter...

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]
```

Based on the several posts available online for this adapter, I have so far tried various combinations of different drivers available.

Finally, I'm at the 2nd solution offered in this page...
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

i.e. I'm using brcmsmac module. Blacklisted the following...

```
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
blacklist wl
blacklist ssb
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Added brcmsmac to /etc/modules list.

But my rfkill listing still shows the interface to be hardware blocked...

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes <<<<
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

But my hardware switch seems to be on. (There is a single switch for bluetooth and wifi, and bluetooth is working fine)

dmesg shows error during brcmsmac driver loading...

```
$ dmesg|grep brcmsmac
[   16.664016] brcmsmac bcma0:0: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 17
[   16.698271] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 243
[   25.018128] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_start: brcms_up() returned -132
```

After some googling, I see that 132 errno corresponds to ERFKILL, indicating that the interface is hardware blocked.

So, is this really a hardware problem? Or some bug in driver code? 
Any suggestions on how to conclude, without having to try other OSes to check?

Answer (score 0):

The module *bcma* is a dependency of *brcmsmac*; I suggest you undo its blacklist. Also, I'd try blacklisting *ideapad-laptop* and not *acer-wmi*.

Comment: Tried this combination too. Didn't help. The driver fails with same error message as above. rfkill listing still shows hardware blocked. unblocking doesn't help.